# extra argument for Ocaml and it's still working

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I found this type `zipper` and `insert` functions defined like this:

```
type 'a zipper = 'a list * int;;

exception Empty

let empty = ([], 0)

let insert ((l, n): 'a zipper) (a: 'a) : 'a zipper =
  let rec ins ll nn =
    if nn = 0 then a::ll 
    else 
      match ll with
      | [] -> raise Empty 
      | h::q -> h::(ins q (nn-1))
  in 
  (ins l n, n)
```

What I don't get is this part `in (ins l n, n)`. `ins` take two arguments, apparently `ll` is a list, and `nn` is an integer, but why in the call `in (ins l n, n)` we calling it this way, with a `zipper` and an integer? Can you explain what is going on please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it with a simpler function, `f`, which builds a tuple from two values:

```
# let f a b = (a,b)
val f : 'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b = <fun>
```

When writing a call to `f` as above for `ins`, we have the following:

```
# (f 1 2, 3)
- : (int * int) * int = ((1, 2), 3)
```

So `f 1 2` is grouped as a function call, producing `(1, 2)`, and this result is also grouped with `3` in another tuple.

Comment: right, but when we call `(ins l n, n)` that would recursively go to `ins (l, n), n` which means that `(l,n)` is `ll` and `n` for `nn`, but how can we match `ll` as if it were a list, does ocaml infers that we want to match a list only out of the tuple. `match ll with []`... when `ll = (l,n)`? –

Comment: the syntax is such as it is equivalent to `((ins l n), n)`; when calling `(ins l n)`, `ll` is bound to `l` and `nn` is bound to `n` in the recursive call; (maybe you are confusing `ins` and `insert`?)

Answer (score 3):

`(ins l n, n)` is equivalent to `let x = ins l n in (x, n)` or `((ins l n), n)`.

It's not an extra argument, the comma actually has a purpose here, which is to construct a tuple of the values on its left and right side.

Answer (score 2):

Your key misunderstanding here seems to center around [associativity and precendence](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#ss%3Aprecedence-and-associativity). At that link you'll find a table.  Note the position of function application: it's quite high on the list. And the `,` for creating tuples is quite low on the list.

So, as noted in the other answers, `(ins l n, n)` is directly equivalent to `((ins l n), n)`.

To pick another example, let's look at:

```
h::(ins q (nn-1))
```

Note that function application again has higher precedence than `::`, so we can also write this as:

```
h :: ins q (nn - 1)
```

It's good to understand this because you'll see it frequently when reading OCaml source code.

To take that last one a step further, `::` does have *higher* precedence than `@@`, so the following will not compile:

```
h :: ins q @@ nn - 1
```

Because it parses as:

```
(h :: ins q) @@ (nn - 1)
```

Rather than:

```
h :: (ins q @@ (nn - 1))
```